# Rails has one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I am working on building a portfolio section in my website right now. I have it set where a portfolio has one category that is associated with it.

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :category
end
```

I am trying to access the category attribute name in the show view for the portfolio , but I am getting this error.

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: categories.portfolio_id: SELECT  "categories".* FROM "categories" WHERE "categories"."portfolio_id" = ? LIMIT ?
```

This is what is in the view:

```
<li><i class="icon_link"></i><span>Category: </span><%= @portfolio.category.name %></li>
```

I remembering using this syntax before and not having any problems with it. Any help would be great. I tried to find this question on here =, but could not make of them work.

Comment: Are you sure a better association wouldn't be a belongs_to association with Category. So Portfolio belongs_to :category and Category has_many :portfolios. Then your view would work.

Answer (score 2):

Rails conventional naming for has_one/belongs_to associations is - if you have `category_id` column in `Portfolio` then "a portfolio belongs_to a category" and "a category has one portfolio". You need to rewrite your models as:

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :portfolio
```

After that `@portfolio.category.name` should work fine.

**Update:** Possibly "a category has many portfolios", when the models will be:

```
class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :portfolio
```

Comment: You may read details about has_one/belongs_to association in Rails documentation http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-belongs-to-and-has-one

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you have an association in rails, there has to be at least two entites (or models) involved in that association. In your particular case, you've associated a `Portfolio` with a `Category` via the `has_one` association. However, you need to specify the association on the `Category` end as well. So in your `Category.rb` model class, you need to write:

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :portfolio    
  # other stuff
end
```

There's one more step to ensuring that the association is working properly. You need to make sure that the `categories` table in your database has a field called `portfolio_id`. If it does, then you should be good to go! If it doesn't then do the following:

1. Type `rails generate migration addPortfolioIdToCategory` in your terminal
2. Open up the migration file and ensure it looks like this:

   ```
   def change
     add_column :categories, :portfolio_id, :integer
   end
   ```
3. Now run `rake db:migrate` from your terminal

If you reload your server, your problem should be solved!

#### NOTE

The model that specifies the `belongs_to` association must have the primary key attribute in the corresponding database table. In your case, if the `Category` model has the `belongs_to` association, then the `categories` database table must have the field titled `portfolio_id`.

Answer (score 0):

It's complaining portfolio_id doesn't exist on your categories table. Verify your migration file for categories. Given the foreign key is set on categories it should work. [Rails has one association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-one-association)

Comment: it doesn't exist because I just have category_id in portfolio

Comment: I linked the docs so you can see the example. You should move portfolio_id to categories table if you want has_one : category on your portfolios model

Comment: The category database is just a list of all the categories and then I reference which on it is in the portfolio record with category_id

Comment: It sounds like you want to use belongs_to :category instead of has_one